# How to fetch Cyrillic domain like "http://ньюбаланс.рф" with Apache HTTP Client?

Tags: java, android, http, utf-8, apache-httpclient-4.x

Using `httpclient` for `org.apache.httpcomponents` version `4.3.6` I try to perform `GET` request to domain names like `http://ньюбаланс.рф` by `new HttpGet(url)`, but it ends up with the following error:

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: ?????????.??
at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:907)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1302)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1255)
...
```

The url variable has proper UTF-8 value - it is definatelly not buil up from '?' characters.

How to send request to such domain names?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to encode the domain name to puny code before resolving the domain.

```
final encodedDomain = IDN.toASCII(unicodeDomain);
```

Check also the Android documentation here: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/IDN.html

Answer (score 2):

I've found the solution

```
"http://"+IDN.toASCII(domain);
```